# What is the name of the shape formed by a semicircle attached to a rectangle?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I will be asking several questions like this. I have to figure out the names of the shapes of numerous parts that we make.  I have looked, but the internet has failed me for several shapes. Here's the first one:

[image]

It's basically a rectangle with a semicircle on top of it. Don't know if it would have a different name if it was a square instead of a rectangle, but it really doesn't matter.

Thank you very much for all your help and all your help to come for my other shape questions.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/3zyxbi/is_there_a_name_for_this_shape_semicircle_fused/

Comment: Can you give us some context as to why you are and will be asking about names for various shapes, if there are names?  What motivates this question? Is this for a class, or some research, for architecture, or engineering?

Comment: "Norman window" (an answer to the reddit post linked above) seems to yield results on Google.  Not sure if there are other common names for this.

Comment: And for what it's worth, it's not at all clear what those arrows are supposed to indicate.

Comment: I once attended a talk by Underwood Dudley, in which he quoted a problem found in most calculus textbooks, that began by describing a window in the shape of a rectangle surmounted by a semicircle, and then said that is the sole surviving use of the word "surmount" in the English language. As a consequence, I have noticed occasions when that word is used. We can surmount this difficulty, etc.

Comment: When posting additional questions, please describe the shape in the title (as I did in my edit), so that we don't have to sift through a bunch of indistinguishable "What is the name of this shape?" questions.

Comment: In a class I teach we do call this a norman window! Whether or not people would be familiar with this term I don't know.

Comment: Since you are doing the asking you can make up names for the shapes that don't have accepted names. For shapes that do have names where the names are uncommonly used you'll have to provide them anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I was going to make the same remark about that classic calculus problem. Without prompting by Dudley (or anyone else that I can recall), I have also told students that they'd never encounter the word "surmount" outside of that problem ... only to remember "surmount a difficulty" sometime later. At least now I know that I had the same insight/oversight as Dudley. :)

Comment: Thank you very much!
Sure, the reason I ask is, one of the many things we do at work is die cut parts, and I have to come up with names for the shapes and parts we make. I try to be as accurate as I can. The arrows and lines are just there to show the dimensions of the shape. I didn't know if you'd need them or not.

Comment: Some other shape name suggestions which do return results: bullet, elliptical ogive, rounded arch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made this reasoning: an eyelet consists of two semicircles and a rectangle (or two semirectangle), then a semicircle and a semirectangle will be called a semieyelet.

Answer (score 4):

there is a shape called a stadium. you could call this shape a half stadium.

Wikipedia link to the stadium shape
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stadium_(geometry)#:~:text=A%20stadium%20is%20a%20two,%2C%20obround%2C%20or%20sausage%20body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stadium_(geometry)#:%7E:text=A%20stadium%20is%20a%20two,%2C%20obround%2C%20or%20sausage%20body).

Comment: since we're using semicircles, calling a half stadium a “semistadium” might also apply